# Improve SQL Left Join Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

is there a way to improve the performance of following command?

```
SELECT c.symbol
     , c.currency 
  FROM company c 
  LEFT 
  JOIN Bilanz b
    ON c.symbol = b.symbol 
 WHERE b.symbol IS NULL
```

Comment: You can try using `NOT EXISTS`, you'd need to compare the explains to see which should be better.  Probably not a significant difference though.

Comment: Show us the table definitions

**You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Answer (score 0):

You want an index on `bilanz(symbol)`.

There might be a small difference between the performance of `left join` and `not exists`.  But both will use the index.